# Threading in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

Just looking for something ultra simple. I need to spawn a method off to a new thread.

1. I don't care when or how it ends.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Comment: If did decide you wanted to receive updates on the thread's progress and handle the ending of the piece of work you might find the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) helpful

Comment: A normal thread and events can do that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Thread thread=new Thread(() => {
  // thread code here
});

thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 9):

For starting a new thread in winforms, the `ThreadPool` is hard to beat for simplicity:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => 
{
    // put whatever should be done here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When using Winforms you could also use the 'BackgroundWorker'

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness... With .Net 4.0 you have the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Simple example....

```
  Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    ...doing stuff in a thread...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this MDSN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) about the Thread Pool. This should have you ask for new threads and other thread realted stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the MSDN page for the class `System.Threading`, they've got an easy sample there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A short program that never stops saying "Hello!", using a thread.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace Treading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread noiseMaker = new Thread(Noisy);
            noiseMaker.Start();
        }

        public static void Noisy()
        {
            while(true)
                Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simpliest way to do it :

1 : you create a function that contains the code you want to execute :

```
public static void ThreadProc() {
     // Write what ou want here !
     // And here :-)   

    }
```

2 : Start the new thread just by creating one with the function you've just create as the parameter :

```
public static void Main() {

Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
```

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)