# IsolatedStorage Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

How to view contents of Isolated storage on windows phone 8 app on like the IsoStoreSpy for windows phone 7.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) seem to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is : ISETool.exe , which is a command line tool that fullfill your needs.

Comment: Please avoid signing your posts.

Comment: (You were already told this [back on the 10th](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14267278/560648).)